# elasticsearch query on all array elements

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I search for documents that have all of the specified tags in the following query? I tried minimum_should_match and "execution": "and", but none of them is supported in my query.

```
GET products/fashion/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "constant_score": {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {"terms" : {
              "tags" : ["gucci", "dresses"]
            }},
            {"range" : {
              "price.value" : {
                "gte" : 100,
                "lt" : 1000
              }
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": { "date": { "order": "desc" }}
}
```

====== UPDATE

I found a way to build my queries. The task was to reproduce the following mongodb query in the elasticsearch:

```
{
  "tags": {
    "$all":["gucci","dresses"]
  },
  "price.value":{"$gte":100,"$lte":1000}
}
```

And here is my elasticsearch query

```
GET products/fashion/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [
        {"term" : {
          "tags" : "gucci"
        }},
        {"term" : {
          "tags" : "dresses"
        }},
        {"range" : {
          "price.value" : {
            "gte" : 100,
            "lt" : 1000
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the mapping and a few sample documents?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a mapping defined for your index?  By default, Elasticsearch will analyze string fields.  If you want to find exact terms like you are above, you need to specify them as `not_analyzed` in the mapping.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_filter_with_text